# django less compilation to css empty css

Tags: django, less

I have gone through a no of tutorials but cant able to compile less to css
What is the best technique to compile less to css in django. (Static precomiler, yui, e.t.c)

Can you provide me some reasonable detail to configure less to django. because when i compiles it produces the empty css

And what is less binary path.

Comment: What are you currently doing which is producing the empty file?

Comment: Ihave used the following settings in my settings.py STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'pipeline.storage.PipelineStorage'
PIPELINE_COMPILERS = (
    'pipeline.compilers.less.LessCompiler',
)

PIPELINE_CSS_COMPRESSOR = 'pipeline.compressors.cssmin.CSSMinCompressor'
                                                      PIPELINE_CSSMIN_BINARY = 'cssmin'


PIPELINE_LESS_BINARY = 'lessc'
LESS_EXECUTABLE = getattr(settings, "LESS_EXECUTABLE", "lessc")